# why the overflow:hidden creates BFC(Block Formatting Context)?

Tags: css

I learned that the overflow:hidden just handles the context which overflows the box in which it is contained.

BUT why the overflow:hidden creates block formatting context?

What is the relationship between those two? (handling the context which overflows vs creating new block formatting context.)

I`ve already tried to read other articles but i cannot understand "why"

Do I just have to memorize?

desperately need some help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the overflow property with a value different to visible (its
>   default) will create a **new block formatting context**. This is
>   technically *necessary* — if a float intersected with the scrolling
>   element it would forcibly rewrap the content. The rewrap would happen
>   after each scroll step, leading to a slow scrolling experience.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i didnt catch what your meaning of "intersect with the scrolling element" and "scroll step".. i m a novice in css, so could you please explain about this issue more in detail if you dont mind?